# Forcing SSL with www in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have set the redirect in CPanel to push all traffic to go to https in htaccess. The cPanel "Add Redirect" option had `https?://(www.)?` but the www portion does not redirect to https using

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have managed to get the www portion working using the code below, but unsure whether the `RewriteEngine On` is still required and whether lines 2 and 3 that cPanel has inserted are also required as I have never seen them referenced in many htaccess articles.

Could you help me compact this into one block which works for the domain and any pages accessed?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example\.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```